# In Age of Empires 3, is there any difference between the campaign in the standard game vs. in Asian Dynasties?

Tags: age-of-empires-iii

I recently finished playing the campaign in Age of Empires 3 (the standard game, with no expansion packs).

Now I started playing the Asian Dynasties expansion pack. I noticed that from there too I can play the standard game's campaign, but it doesn't recognize the progress I already made.

Is there any difference at all between playing that campaign from the standard game vs. from Asian Dynasties?